# Imprimir el valor de una variable con php

Tags: php, laravel

¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor de una variable que proviene de una consulta a la base de datos? Quiero saber que valor me trae esa consulta y para ello necesito imprimirla en consola.

Comment: Puedes compartirnos algo de código ? de qué forma estás haciendo la consulta? y la consulta en sí.

Comment: Hola LLaza, por favor detalla más tu pregunta, de la forma que está hasta el momento no es posible responderla. Por favor lee: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: En vez de hacer una serie de preguntas mal-formuladas (y recibidas con -1), podías tomar unos minutos para navegar por el site y ver como funciona... (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este es un ejemplo básico:

En tu controlador iría así:

```
$data = DB::table('data')->where('id','3')->first();
return View::make('hello',['data'=>$data->info]);
```

Donde:

`table('data')table('data')` Es el nombre de la tabla.

`where('id','3')` Extrae los datos donde
 `id=3`.

`'hello'` Es el nombre de la vista en donde se quiere mostrar los datos.

`['data'=>$data->info]` Mostrará la info de la tabla.

Ahora en la vista colocas esto:

```
{{ $data }}
```

Esta variable mostrará los datos de `['data'=>$data->info]`.

En consola no se exactamente como imprimir directamente, pero va así:

```
    Log::info("mensaje: " . $variable);
```

Para mas info click [aquí](http://tutorials.scrisoft.com/update-insert-delete-and-display-data-from-database-with-laravel/)